# Comprehensive SPICE guide

Tags: ltspice, spice

I am using LTSpice for simulation, but I am finding that I have to look through many different online sources to find what I am looking for e.g. the section on analog behavioral modeling here http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/SPICEsummary.htm

Is there a free comprehensive guide that includes all of SPICE's features or do I need to get one of the SPICE books? I am reluctant because they all seem too old.

Something specific to LTSpice would be even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, the independent users group on Yahoo is an excellent community resource for questions about Spice in general and LTSpice specifically.

For reference information and base-line documentation, the built-in help actually contains a wealth of information, although it is not always easy to narrow down on the relevant section. I usually use the "index" tab to find stuff instead of the "contents" tab.

For example, the circuit element syntax that you linked to is all covered in the help under the "circuit elements" section. The "waveform arithmetic" page is definitely worth a read for understanding the built-in calculator functions which can be used both for defining arbitrary behavioral sources and writing evaluative .measure statements.

I frequently see even relatively obscure LTSpice questions posted here on Stack Exchange and in the user group that are answered somewhere in the built-in help. It's usually worth a check before you look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best resource I've found for LTSpice have come from the [Yahoo group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/LTspice/info).

Lots of guides, models, circuits, and experts helping other users.